# Turn OFF self-closing tags in SimpleXML for PHP?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm building an XML document with PHP's SimpleXML extension, and I'm adding a token to the file:

```
$doc->addChild('myToken');
```

This generates (what I know as) a self-closing or single tag:

```
<myToken/>
```

However, the aging web-service I'm communicating with is tripping all over self-closing tags, so I need to have a separate opening and closing tag:

```
<myToken></myToken>
```

The question is, how do I do this, outside of running the generated XML through a **preg_replace**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation at [SimpleXMLElement->__construct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-element-construct.php) and [LibXML Predefined Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php), I think this should work:

```
<?php
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($someData, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);

// some processing here

$out = $sxe->asXML();
?>
```

Try that and see if it works. Otherwise, I'm afraid, it's preg_replace-land.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the value to something empty (i.e. null, empty string) it will use open/close brackets.

```
$tag = '<SomeTagName/>';

echo "Tag: '$tag'\n\n";

$x = new SimpleXMLElement($tag);
echo "Autoclosed: {$x->asXML()}\n";

$x = new SimpleXMLElement($tag);
$x[0] = null;
echo "Null: {$x->asXML()}\n";

$x = new SimpleXMLElement($tag);
$x[0] = '';
echo "Empty: {$x->asXML()}\n";
```

See example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/10642a84dca5a50eba882a347f152fc480bc47b5

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, it is not possible to avoid self closing tags wiht LibXML. One of the proposed solution by @Piskvor will not work:

LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG does not work with simplexml, as mentionned [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php):

```
This option is currently just available in the DOMDocument::save and DOMDocument::saveXML functions.
```

A workaround for that will be to use the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629379/how-to-prevent-self-closing-tag-in-php-simplexml#answer-19630648)

Comment: This appears to be a response to the existing answer, not an answer to the question, so should be added as a comment under that answer.

Answer (score 1):

May be not the best solution but got same problem and solved it with using pre_replace to change all the self closing tags to full form...

```
$xml_reader = new XMLReader;
$xml_reader->open($xml_file);

$data = preg_replace('/\<(\w+)\s*\/\s*\>/i', '<$1></$1>', $xml_reader->readOuterXML());
```

Answer (score 0):

`LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG` works but only if you use `DOMDocument::save` or `DOMDocument::saveXML`

```
$dom = dom_import_simplexml(SimpleXMLElement)->ownerDocument;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->save($save_path, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```