# How to prevent self closing tag in php simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I want to generate xml by using php simplexml.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

$output = $xml->addChild('child1');
$output->addChild('child2', "value");
$output->addChild('noValue', '');

Header('Content-type: text/xml');
print($xml->asXML());
```

The output is

```
<xml>
   <child1>
      <child2>value</child2>
      <noValue/>
   </child1>
</xml>
```

What I want is if the tag has no value it should display like this

```
<noValue></noValue>
```

I've tried using `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG` from [Turn OFF self-closing tags in SimpleXML for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259719/turn-off-self-closing-tags-in-simplexml-for-php)

I've tried `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>', LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);` and it doesn't work. So I don't know where to put the `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG`

Comment: Umm, doesn't it tell you where to put it in the page you link to?

Comment: Yes, I've tried `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>', LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);` but the output still the same `<noValue/>`.

Comment: [Confirmed](http://3v4l.org/WO3Mb). Edit: Huh, it seems it's related to your PHP setup. On 3v4l and Ideone I still got the self-closing tag, while on my localhost PHP 5.4 I got the expected result.

Comment: `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG` only works with `DOMDocument`, which means you need to use `dom_import_simplexml` to use your simplexml object with that option. See my answer.

Comment: With the content-type explicitly set to `text/xml` a strict XML parser would throw an error when an empty element was encountered. Any reason this element must be empty and not self-closing? Just curious if this is imposed by a common api or library ( as it should be fixed eventually )

Comment: @Passerby: It seems your answer is also correct. While I see the page source, it display what I desired. Where is your answer Passerby?

Comment: @Wakanina Combined my comments as an answer. Although I kind of like Anthony's answer, as he/she explains why the empty tag is not guaranteed to produce.

Comment: Anthony = "he" ; and the explanation is as noted: that option is not available to simplexml. And as I elaborated, it shouldn't be since empty tags are invalid XML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turn OFF self-closing tags in SimpleXML for PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259719/turn-off-self-closing-tags-in-simplexml-for-php)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG` does not work with simplexml, per the [spec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php):

> This option is currently just available in the DOMDocument::save and DOMDocument::saveXML functions.

To achieve what you're after, you need to convert the simplexml object to a DOMDocument object:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
$child1 = $xml->addChild('child1');
$child1->addChild('child2', "value");
$child1->addChild('noValue', '');
$dom_sxe = dom_import_simplexml($xml);  // Returns a DomElement object

$dom_output = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom_output->formatOutput = true;
$dom_sxe = $dom_output->importNode($dom_sxe, true);
$dom_sxe = $dom_output->appendChild($dom_sxe);

echo $dom_output->saveXML($dom_output, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

which returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
  <child1>
    <child2>value</child2>
    <noValue></noValue>
  </child1>
</xml>
```

Something worth pointing out... the likely reason that the NOEMPTYTAG option is available for DOMDocument and not simplexml is that empty elements are not considered valid XML, while the DOM specification allows for them. You are banging your head against the wall to get invalid XML, which may suggest that the valid self-closing empty element would work just as well.

Comment: @Wakanina - Not sure how I posted the answer twice, but this is the one I updated to correct for the `DOMELement` error in initial answer.

Comment: Anthony, Mike, and Passerby: Ok guys your answers are correct, but I prefer to use Anthony's method because it's easy for me to implement it to my app. I just have to convert my simplexml object to DOMDocument object, so I don't rebuild it from begining. Thanks for you all :)

Comment: @Anthony: *"empty elements are not considered valid XML"* - Is it so? Can you give me some pointers on this one, I'd like to learn more about this.

Comment: "valid" may not be the right term. I believe the preferred term would be "well-formed" and it's a bit of a chicken/egg scenario, where an empty element *can* be expressed as `<element></element>` but is well-formed when expressed as `<element />` while at the same time any empty element should be declared (in the DTD) as `EMPTY`, which would suggest that an element can not be optionally empty, so that if `<element>data</element>` is valid, `<element></element>` would not be, as the second would suggest the element is declared as `EMPTY` which would invalidate the first.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed is the part of the spec that addresses the idea of an empty element, though I can't find anywhere that states when `<element></element>` would be allowed (ie when a non-empty element could be empty)

Answer (score 8):

Despite the quite lengthy answers already given - which are not particularly wrong and do shed some light into some libxml library internals and it's PHP binding - you're most likely looking for:

```
$output->noValue = '';
```

To add an open tag, empty node-value and end tag (beautified, demo is here: http://3v4l.org/S2PKc):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
  <child1>
    <child2>value</child2>
    <noValue></noValue>
  </child1>
</xml>
```

Just noting as it seems it has been overlooked with the existing answers.

Comment: I discovered the same thing -- just set the value to something empty  http://stackoverflow.com/a/29581022/1037948

Comment: Oh that's interesting. If you set it as having no value when adding as a child, it is handled as empty element, but if you update it to have no value, it treats it as a non-empty element with no value. Testing a bit further, this even works with `$output->noValue = null;`

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm :)

Comment: This is very neat, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since Simple XML is proving troublesome, perhaps XMLWriter could do what you want.

Here's a [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/yqj-gk9)

```
<?php

$oXMLWriter = new XMLWriter;
$oXMLWriter->openMemory();
$oXMLWriter->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$oXMLWriter->startElement('xml');
$oXMLWriter->writeElement('child1', 'Hello world!!');
$oXMLWriter->writeElement('noValue', '');
$oXMLWriter->endElement();

$oXMLWriter->endDocument();
echo htmlentities($oXMLWriter->outputMemory(TRUE));

?>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xml>
    <child1>Hello world!!</child1>
    <noValue></noValue>
  </xml>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, it works. But I want to display it as xml page. I tried add `Header('Content-type: text/xml');` before `echo`, and it `error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty`. How to display it as xml page?

Comment: I added htmlentities() so that the output would display completely on a page. Add your header and change the last line to `echo $oXMLWriter->outputMemory(TRUE);`

Comment: (psst, not sure if you flagged to migrate [this steaming pile of dung](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615856/27-ips-lcd-monitor?noredirect=1), but I think [superuser may put out a hit on you for it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203172/migrated-question-not-marked-as-migrated-on-source-site))

Comment: @MikeW: Aaah, so it does!

Answer (score 0):

Extending from my comments (some got deleted):

The behavior depends on your environment. This same code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>', LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);

$output = $xml->addChild('child1');
$output->addChild('child2', "value");
$output->addChild('noValue', '');

echo $xml->asXML();
```

In [3v4l.org](http://3v4l.org/WO3Mb) and [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/miW9tg), it produces self-closing tag;
In [eval.in](https://eval.in/57961), [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/wZHA7XKQ) and on my localhost (PHP 5.3/5.4, libXML 2.7, Windows), it produces empty tag.

Since according to [PHP document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php#constant.libxml-noemptytag), `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG` only (guarenteed to) work in [`DOM`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), you may want to try `DOM` for ensurance:

```
$dom=new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
$dom->formatOutput=true;
$root=$dom->createElement("xml");
$dom->appendChild($root);
$child1=$dom->createElement("child1");
$root->appendChild($child1);
$node=$dom->createElement("child2");
$node->appendChild($dom->createTextNode("value"));
$child1->appendChild($node);
$node=$dom->createElement("noValue");
$child1->appendChild($node);
echo $dom->saveXML($dom,LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

[3v4l.org demo](http://3v4l.org/38Y34).

**Edit**:

All the above online demo site uses `Content-Type: text/plain` by default. If you want to directly output XML to browser as a standalone resource, you can specify the header before output:

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo $dom->saveXML($dom,LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to get the child node and asign to the nodeValue property an empty string, and the xml close tag appears.

`$output->childNodes[1]->nodeValue = '';`

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, all the solutions proposed here didn't help me. I had to process the result with the **`preg_replace`** function. Correct the template if you have anything other than letters and numbers in the property names.

```
echo preg_replace("/\<([\w\d]+)\/\>/ui", "<$1></$1>", $xml->asXML());
```