# how to avoid shortcut closed xml tags if value is empty in simplexml addChild?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I created a xml generator using PHP SimpleXML, the problem now is, whenever there are empty values, the element that was added is inserting a shortcut closed tag, instead of a complete tag. like e.g

instead of this

```
<mytag></mytag>
```

the output is giving me this

```
<mytag/>
```

how to fix this issue with the `addChild()` of simpleXMLElement of PHP ?

Comment: What is your version of using `addChild()`?

Comment: `<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><Items></Items>`

Comment: No, what is the code you used so far?

Comment: Surely you mean `<mytag/>`, not `</mytag>`.  The latter is not valid XML without a separate opening tag.

Comment: I edited my post to <mytag/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-closing tags are a normal part of XML, so normally, you should just not worry about them.  However, if you really want to avoid them and use the full `<mytag></mytag>` even when empty, SimpleXML doesn't have that option but DOM does, and you can convert to DOM when you output.

For example, if you're using

```
$xml->asXML()
```

Change it to

```
dom_import_simplexml($xml)->ownerDocument->saveXML(null, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

Comment: am using `fwrite($file,$xml->asXML())`..while this one `fwrite($file,$xml->asXML(null,LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG))` , gave me an error

Comment: Ah sorry, SimpleXML doesn't have the same option.

Comment: Can you provide the line of your code that's generating that error?

Comment: I managed to make it work with the help of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629379/how-to-prevent-self-closing-tag-in-php-simplexml