# Simple XML Serialization - Disable Self closing tag

Tags: android, android-xml, simple-framework

I'm using in my app this library: http://simple.sourceforge.net/

It will generate this XML:

```
<Hlavicka dat_odesl="2019-05-30T17:08:28+02:00" uuid_zpravy="ffd8ea09-3ecc-47b8-8203-0b1894f9c249"/>
```

But I don't want self closing tag `/>` but classic end tag `</Hlavicka>`. So it should be:

```
<Hlavicka dat_odesl="2019-05-30T17:08:28+02:00" uuid_zpravy="ffd8ea09-3ecc-47b8-8203-0b1894f9c249"></Hlavicka>
```

How can I do it?

Similar question but for PHP is this: [How to prevent self closing tag in php simplexml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629379/how-to-prevent-self-closing-tag-in-php-simplexml)

Comment: Note that SimpleXML in PHP and Simple XML in Java have no relationship, other than handling XML, and being "simple".